# populate json obect array into df table using pyspark?

Tags: json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, apache-spark-dataset

I have values for a column in a df coming as json objects array

```
[
    {
        "name": "ben",
        "apartment": "dfg9",
        "isitflag": false,
        "iscruxflag": false,
        "hisindexnum": 2,
        "valueinb": "110jb",
 
    },
    {
        "name": "bol",
        "apartment": "ran",
        "isitflag": false,
        "iscruxflag": false,
        "hisindexnum": 2,
        "valueinb": "110jb"
    },
    {
        "name": "dol",
        "apartment": "hele",
        "isitflag": false,
        "iscruxflag": false,
        "hisindexnum": 2,
        "valueinb": "110jb"
    }
]
```

I would need to take this value column from previous pd and populate it into a new table with those keys as indes of the table and values as rows in pyspark?

I understand this question seems like lack of trying but as a newbie in pyspark, tried few things but looking if any pyspark expert to steer in guidance

Comment: can you show us one concrete example of your expected output?

Comment: Also, what is the type of this column? array of ... ? please use `df.printSchema()`